# C# SerialPort GetPortNames doesn't work on windows 10

Tags: c#, arduino-uno, serial-communication

I'd made a simple program one or two years ago in windows 8 or windows 8.1 that provides serial port connection between Arduino Uno and my C# Form Application. Firstly I check all open com ports in pc and get these ports for connection choice. To do that working code is like given below for those days;

```
private void portCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string item in System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames())
            {
                //store the each retrieved available port names into the Listbox...    
                if (!portBox.Items.Contains(item))
                { portBox.Items.Add(item); }
            }
        }
```

I'm not opened this program for a long while and now I format my computer and make a clean install with windows 10 Education. And when I run this project I realize the program does not found any open com port. It does not enter the foreach loop, simply System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames() doesn't return any port name. 
I made some research and read about an issue like this situation in windows 10.
And peoples gives completely different solutions about serial connections.
I don't want to rewrite whole project. So is there anyone know anything about this problem? Is there any simple solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you certain that the serial port itself is working correctly after the upgrade to Windows 10?

- Does it appear in Device Manager?
- Does it appear in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM` (which is where [SerialPort.GetPortNames()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames(v=vs.110).aspx) gets its information)?

Anecdotally, I maintain software that uses SerialPort.GetPortNames() to enumerate serial ports and it works fine on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but since it wasn't solved and since I just experienced this same issue on a new Win10 laptop, I thought I'd share my solution.  I finally figured out that I had to download the VCP driver from Silicon Labs, and after I ran the x64 installer everything worked.
I don't think I had to do this on my Win7 laptop so this is an inconvenience of Win10.

Answer (score 0):

Мy problem (Win10) is that when removing the device from the USB, the corresponding port does not disappear from the list (SerialPort.GetPortNames(), C#)
And it's stay even in the registers.
I see:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM]
"\\Device\\USBSER000"="COM11"
"\\Device\\USBSER002"="COM53"
"\\Device\\VCP0"="COM4"
"\\Device\\USBSER001"="COM11"
```

I understand when the problem occurs, but I do not understand how to bypass it: when I occupy the port and turn off the device from USB, the port name remains in the registers and in the list that Windows returns.
[image]